# bootstrap toggle does not work on IPhone X Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

I have the following. using bootstrap 3.xx

```
<span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#prod-select" class="filter-toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

css

```
 .filter-toggle {
     color: #2D76C8 !important;
     float: right;
 }
```

But this does not work when click in Safari on IOS (Iphone X)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add your HTML & CSS Code Here

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I added it

Comment: Filter parent HTML, content HTML where? add your code here : https://jsfiddle.net/